# Counting unique occurrences of ids using MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I am trying to count the unique occurrences of teacherids for each year.  I am sure the results are not unique.

My query

```
SELECT DISTINCT count (tblTeachers.TeacherID) AS uniqueTeacherCount, tblSchoolYears.SchoolYear

FROM tblTeachers INNER JOIN tblTeacher_Building 
.
.

GROUP BY tblSchoolYears.SchoolYear
ORDER BY tblSchoolYears.SchoolYear DESC;
```

The results (that are counting duplicates of TeacherID)

[image]

I have also tried

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT tblTeachers.TeacherID) AS uniqueTeacherCount, tblSchoolYears.SchoolYear

FROM tblTeachers INNER JOIN tblTeacher_Building 
.
.

GROUP BY tblSchoolYears.SchoolYear
ORDER BY tblSchoolYears.SchoolYear DESC;
```

What am I missing?

Thank you

Comment: Is this `sql-server` or `ms-access`?

Comment: If you want an Access query, you can't `use Count(DISTINCT ...)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Select Count(TeacherID) AS uniqueTeacherCount,SchoolYear
from
(
SELECT DISTINCT tblTeachers.TeacherID, tblSchoolYears.SchoolYear
FROM tblTeachers INNER JOIN tblTeacher_Building 
.
.
) hlp
GROUP BY SchoolYear
ORDER BY SchoolYear DESC;
```

Answer (score 1):

You're close. I think this is what you're looking for:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM
(
SELECT DISTINCT count (tblTeachers.TeacherID) AS uniqueTeacherCount, tblSchoolYears.SchoolYear ...
)
```